# How to remove node version 0.12 from Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-14.04, node-inspector

I had installed node js 0.12 for getting the harmony features.
But now on my project development, I am using nvm so that I can have multiple node versions. I have made default version as 0.10.34. And so whenever I type this command:

```
node --version
```

I am getting version as 0.10.34. This is fine.

But on installing some of the packages like node-inspector, the following warning is coming and my debugger is not working properly on installing.

```
engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
```

the debugger gives error like:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.4/node-v11-linux-x64/debug.node'
Runtime.getProperties failed.
ReferenceError: frame_index is not defined
```

According to npm installer, the version is still 0.12.
I have searched a lot to remove this version but cannot find any working solution.

Comment: How did you install it? With `apt-get` or something else?

Comment: no, it was done using a curl request

Comment: it was from the accepted answer from http://askubuntu.com/questions/586671/installing-latest-node-js-through-ppa-not-a-duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

to uninstall the 0.12.x version of nodejs. If your experience is like mine on Ubuntu 14.04,that also uninstalled npm.

The script that you got using curl added the file
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

Remove that file

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

Then execute

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

It will install node 0.10.x.

You will also need to re-create the soft link if you plan to type

> node

from the command line.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Finally, re-install npm

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove node and npm completely and then install a fresh version with https://github.com/creationix/nvm. With nvm you can manage several node versions easily.

There are also other alternatives for managing node versions like https://github.com/tj/n or nave